# Пишу IRC клиент для Freenode. Как правильно авторизоваться?

Tags: python, python-3.x, irc

Если что, клиент на Python. 
Не могу понять, как авторизоваться. Какие именно аргументы писать в USER? Получаю две ошибки: "No Ident response" и "You have not registered", хотя пользователь существует и пароль правильный. Нашёл в гугле, что в IDENT надо писать сервер, но ошибки те же.

Подскажите пожалуйста правильный метод авторизации.

Comment: Только что попробовал telnet'ом: 1) `telnet irc.freenode.net 6667`; 2) `nick Yaant`; 3) `user asdfg 0 * :real name`. Собственно, этого было достаточно.

Comment: Странно. Меня не хочет пускать ни в какую. Просто держит немного, а потом пишет "You have not registered".

Comment: Странно, да. Если тупо telnet'ом подключиться, тоже не пускает? Непосредственно для подключения-то пароль не нужен, это уже после подключения можно авторизоваться через NickServ.

Comment: Поправил. Был некорректный символ в нике, чего я не заметил.